# white spacing between my columns can't overwrite it using css and can't see the css on it showing space

Tags: javascript, css

I have a set of columns with some sliding i am doing between them but then when i arranged them to look like how in my fiddle i found a space between each of them

[image]

[This is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heshamelmasry/b6fw4u0z/), how I can get rid of this spacing to make them attached to each others?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("#switcher1").click(function() {
    jQuery(".middle-wrap").animate({left: "0px"});
  });

  jQuery("#switcher2").click(function() {
    jQuery(".middle-wrap").animate({left: "-198.4px"});
  });

  jQuery("#switcher3").click(function() {
    jQuery(".middle-wrap").animate({left: "-396.8px"});
  });

  jQuery("#switcher4").click(function() {
    jQuery(".middle-wrap").animate({left: "-595.2px"});
  });

  jQuery("#switcher5").click(function() {
    jQuery(".middle-wrap").animate({left: "-793.6px"});
  });

  jQuery("#switcher6").click(function() {
    jQuery(".middle-wrap").animate({left: "-992px"});
  });

  jQuery("#switcher7").click(function() {
    jQuery(".middle-wrap").animate({left: "-1190.4px"});
  });

  jQuery("#switcher8").click(function() {
    jQuery(".middle-wrap").animate({left: "-1388.8px"});
  });

});
```

```css
.outer-wrap {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1050px;
  min-width: 1050px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  transition: all 50ms ease-in-out;
}
.middle-wrap {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1890px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 450px;
  min-width: 1890px;
}

.inner-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 210px;
  min-width: 210px;
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  /*    float: left;*/
}
.year_list {
  background-color: darksalmon;
}
.make_list {
  background-color: red;
}
.model_list {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
.body_style {
  background-color: blue;
}
.transmission {
  background-color:darkviolet;
}
.options {
  background-color: darkslategray;
}
.aftermarket_modifications {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}
.mileage {
  background-color: darkred;
}
.license_plate {
  background-color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="switcher1">See Part 1</div>
<div id="switcher2">See Part 2</div>
<div id="switcher3">See Part 3</div>
<div id="switcher4">See Part 4</div>
<div id="switcher5">See Part 5</div>
<div id="switcher6">See Part 6</div>
<div id="switcher7">See Part 7</div>
<div id="switcher8">See Part 8</div>
<div class="outer-wrap">
  <div class="middle-wrap">
    <div class="inner-wrap year_list"></div>
    <div class="inner-wrap make_list"></div>
    <div class="inner-wrap model_list"></div>
    <div class="inner-wrap body_style"></div>
    <div class="inner-wrap transmission"></div>
    <div class="inner-wrap options"></div>
    <div class="inner-wrap aftermarket_modifications"></div>
    <div class="inner-wrap mileage"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to your `display: inline-blocks`, the white spaces appear in between your block elements.

There are many resolutions to the same, refer to [David Walsh's blog](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

What I would prefer to do here is use `float` instead of `display: inline-block`.

Check updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b6fw4u0z/2/

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment `float: left` in `.inner-wrap` styling

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6fw4u0z/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use display: inline-block then to remove the white space between elements, you can set

```
font-size: 0
```

to them.

See updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b6fw4u0z/3/

You will notice i just put it on all the nested divs.